# Fire emission is cube shaped

Tags: materials, node-editor, particles, smoke-simulation

So heres my problem: Im trying to simulate an explosion (after this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QUrRu7CB6sE&t=221s). But as soon as I crank the emission of the material of the smoke domain up the rendered fire appears cubic. Does Anyone here have an idea that causes this? 
Here's what I see in the viewport[image: Heres what I see in the viewport]

Thats the rendered view
[image: Thats the rendered view]
This is my node setup
[image: This is my node setup]

FOUND THE SOLUTION!
IMPROVED NODE SETUP:
[image: improved node setup]

Comment: Try making your domain bigger or the object smaller!

Comment: Sadly that doesnt change anything

Comment: Alright solved it. The node setup was just wrong. Instead of using a colorramp only u need to plug a multiply from the fac of the attribute to the emission strength in addition to the colorramp

Comment: I was just playing around it, but I didn't get the solution, please answer it below!

Comment: I added a picture to the post as I did not know how to add pictures in answers.